# Trying to Kubernetes Pod in minikube not working

Tags: kubernetes, curl, minikube

I'm currently taking the course "Getting Started with Kubernetes, 3rd Edition" in Oreilly. And I got to the ingress section where you create a deployment, add ingress, add ingress rule and try to access the Pod but it doesn't work.

Without taking into account ingress this is what I did:

1. Create the deployment: `kubectl create deployment nginxlab --image nginx`
2. Expose the Deployment: `kubectl expose deployment nginxlab --port 80`
3. Edit the service to change from ClusterIP to NodePort using: `kubectl edit svc nginxlab`

[image]

I then tried to do a curl and it didn't worked. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. Should this work?

Tried disabling the Firewall and adding rules.

Comment: That all looks fine. It would help to also see the output of `kubectl get pod` to confirm that the nginx pod is running and healthy. Please don't post images of text; just include the text itself, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Have you tried `minikube tunnel` command?

Answer (score 1):

**Identifying  what exactly went wrong with your Minikube Kubernetes cluster**

Essentially, there were a few [troubleshooting steps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-service/#a-pod-cannot-reach-itself-via-service-ip)  you could take to correctly diagnose or debug your problem.

As larks stated to ensure that the nginx pod is operational and healthy, it would be beneficial to also view the results of `kubectl get pod.`

To view more detailed information about a pod, use:

```
kubectl describe pod <name> -n <namespace>
```

Here is the official minikube [Documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) and [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/106784)

Refer to the official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)  to  Set up Ingress on Minikube with the NGINX Ingress Controller